# PHP get rendered image content

Tags: php, image-processing

I have a PHP script that it's purpose is to catch images from a quote image generator, that displays an image after each server request.

So the image is called like this:

```
<img src="gen/123456" alt="" />
```

But, my problem is, that the file that generates the image, is generating another image each time it's called, so after I open my browser and I see the quote, trying to access it's source gives an empty document (The current image id number has been changed, so you cannot access the image from `123456`, because now there's a different number).

How can I get the first generated image which is rendered in the browser's first request, without accessing it's the actual image URL?

Comment: I didn't understand what you want:-D what do mean get the image? it's URL, image itself...

Comment: Do you know if the number changes each pageload, or each time the image is accessed? Try using curl or wget to fetch the page without the image, then find the image url in the retrieved source and fetch that. If that works, then you can write a script that uses curl and regexes to accomplish the same.

Comment: Each time the image is accessed.